# How to attach an attachment which is from email reply

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I'm replying to email(abc@gmail.com) with an attachment. I need to store that attachment in Notes & Attachment of the record. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Share your code? what did you tried so far.

Comment: "replay"? I think you may have meant "reply"?

Comment: Yes, reply.  I haven't tried so far. But I need to implement this scenario. Is there any way to email service(inbound) or writing code?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, you can follow these steps to implement the requirement.

Create an Email Service in Salesforce. Email services are automated processes that use Apex classes to process the contents, headers, and attachments of the inbound emails.

Auto Forward all inbound Emails from *abc@gmail.com* to this Email Service email address.

In the Email service Apex Class, parse the email and get the attachment from the Email and attach to the record.

*I am assuming that you are having the Salesforce Record Id in the Email Subject or Body in a predefined format.*

Please refer this [Blog Post](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/email-services-in-salesforce-with-simple-example/) on how to create an Email Service to Create a Conatct with the attachments present in the Email.